# Stuck setting up multiple network interfaces with one gateway using /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: debian, networking, etc

I'm an advanced noob and I'm running into the limitations of my understanding of how to set up my network. My gateway to the internet should be 10.0.1.1, and I have 2 PCI 10ge nic cards installed to communicate with other devices not on the internet.

I thought I had my /etc/network/interfaces set up correctly so I'm only using 10.0.1.1 as the gateway to the internet, but when I add the first 10ge network interface (192.168.1.100) it seems to throw it off.

I'm still able to ping 1.1.1.1, and devices on the 192.168.1.x network, but when I traceroute 1.1.1.1 it takes over a minute to execute and it's going from 10.0.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 before hopping outside.

I don't see why any outside request is being directed through 192.168.etc... I'm guessing there's another /etc/ doc that I'm not aware about that I need to edit.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on Debian 10, and Below is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface eno1 main connection to network
    allow-hotplug eno1
    auto eno1
    iface eno1 inet static
    address 10.0.1.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.1.0
    broadcast 10.0.1.255
    gateway 10.0.1.1

# iface enp1s (first 10gbe card)
    allow-hotplug enp1s0f0
    auto enp1s0f0
    iface enp1s0f0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: about 192.168.1.254 it could be an other 192.168.1.254 beyond 10.0.1.1 . To confirm this, you'd have to run tcpdump on eno1 and see if you see 192.168.1.254 on it. I still fail to see how this would be a problem and how this would prevent your settings to work

Comment: Thanks @A.B Appreciate the response. No trace of 192.168.* in tcpdump. This is a persnickety issue. Will update the thread when I resolve.